# MySQL connection at localhost failed

Tags: mysql, apache, windows-7

i have been using Apache for a very long time, recently i faced an unexpected error when I tried to connect to MySQL database using SqlYog. Error is as follows:

Error No. 2003
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10060)

I don't why the hell this error appeared out of nowhere. I thought it might be a port issue, so i closed my Skype and again tried to connect to MySql but got this error again. I am using Windows 7, Apache 2.4.4. Someone please help me, I am completely unable to figure out what's going on.

Comment: http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Comment: Solved it, my antivirus (avast) program was blocking the port, once i disabled my antivirus, everything went on smoothly as expected. :)